# Using docker with python packages

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to use [medpy](https://hub.docker.com/r/loli/medpy/) on a Mac OSX. I tried running `docker run loli/medpy` but nothing seems to happen.

And I cannot get pip to install `itk` on my Mac OSX.

Pip install itk shows this error

Collecting itk
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for itk

Comment: Are you seeing errors when attempting to install `itk` with pip? If so please add them to your question.

Comment: Is docker working? What does `docker run hello-world` output?
What does `docker ps -e` output?

Comment: yes docker is working. It says docker is working

Comment: @aceminer It appears the [itk pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/itk/4.9.0) doesn't work properly as I receive the same issue. It looks like `SimpleITK` was created as a simpler interface to `itk`. Which can be installed with `pip install SimpleITK` or `pip install  --trusted-host www.simpleitk.org -f http://www.simpleitk.org/SimpleITK/resources/software.html --timeout 30 SimpleITK` from [SimpleITK's getting started](https://itk.org/Wiki/SimpleITK/GettingStarted).